# Warning: dvar has never been used by the engine

Tags: cplex, mixed-integer-programming, opl

I am trying to solve a MILP (Kasapidis et al. 2021). It contains two sets of decision variables for allocating tasks to a machine and sequencing the tasks on a machine:

```
dvar boolean X[operations][operations][machines]
dvar boolean Y[operations][machines]
```

Beside this, a set of `dvar float+ completionTime[operations]` and `dvar float+ makespan`.

While solving the model, the warning occurs that lots of the decision variables (e.g X#0#0#0, X#0#0#1, X#0#1#1 ... X#2#9#1) have never been used by the engine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry too much since those are warnings, not errors.

```
dvar int x[1..3];

subject to
{
  x[1]==1;
  x[3]==3;
}
```

will give you a warning about x[2] was never used but you could then write

```
{int} s={1,3};

dvar int x[s];

subject to
{
  x[1]==1;
  x[3]==3;
}
```

and then no warning any longer

Answer (score 0):

The warning that you are getting is really an indication that your model is wasteful - you are creating decision variables for e.g. every combination of pairs of operations and machine, when not every combination actually possile. This may be e.g. because not every machine can perform every operation.

It might be better to reformulate the structure of your model to use e.g. sets of tuples like <operation1, operation2, machine> which directly model the possible combinations.